# remove /profile/ from a link

Tags: nginx

On my site my users click on a profile and the link shows up as www.website.com/profile/username and I would like it to only be www.website.com/username - any suggestions on how I can do this

Note: my webserver is nginx so using rewrite rules is ok, but I would want to know how to write them in the config file

Comment: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule

Comment: Might present a problem for the user whose username is profile ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following rewrite rule:

```
rewrite ^/profile/(.*)$ /$1 permanent;
```